# How to write array items like string?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-development-server

*How can I write array items like string.
Example:
[1, 2, 7, 9, 12] = 127912
[John, Mike, Jeremy] = JohnMikeJeremy*

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
const elements = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(elements.join('');
```